# Feeding VBO with data

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Is there any difference if I specify vertex/color data through

- `glVertexPointer/glColorPointer`
- Using `glMapBufferOES` (extension)
- `glBufferData/glBufferSubData`

Can I assume that all methods may equally transfer data into same place and then I can safely enable vertex/color array states using `glEnableClientState`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gl{Vertex,Color,Normal,TexCoord}Pointer` don't transfer data at all. They set the data base pointer in either client (absolute pointer in process address space) or server (offset into buffer object) space, which is the base address for all drawing access into the vertex attribute arrays.

Those were the pears. No come the cherries:

`glMapBuffer` creates a memory mapping of a buffer object into client address space, where one can write/read data from/to. `glBuffer[Sub]Data` copies data from client to server; in the net effect the same could be done by mapping with `glMapBuffer`, writing there and unmapping with `glUnmapBuffer`

You can't compare pears with cherries. (cherries, because apples are too closely related to pears, but *Pointer are so different in their function from glMapBuffer and glBufferData that I had to emphase this).

Comment: ok, now I see the difference. One last thing - the offset that I specify is relative or absolute? Do you specify number of bytes that is representing offset from the beginning of buffer or I specify the address between starting address of the buffer and length?

Comment: @Michael: You specify the number of GLchar from the beginning of the buffer. In the case of VBOs in C++ this takes some weird integer to pointer casting (cast the integer to GLchar*, then cast that to void*). In plain C it's rather simple: Cast the integer to GLchar*, C defines that any pointer can be passed to a void* parameter.

Comment: Just saw one example http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/CodeColony/vertexarrays.php which says: `The last parameter is a pointer to the data. ` and using `... &Vertices[0].r);`.

Comment: OK I see, it's just specifying the color offset in vertex buffer. But the type is not number of GLchars, but rather absolute address.

Comment: @Michael: It's the absolut address if VBOs are **not** used, but the thing is an ordinary vertex array. If it is an VBO it specifies the offset withing the VBO.

Comment: oh, that was very very useful to know! I guess the thing is that if buffer located in GPU premises, you can't know easily the address and the way to specify offset is how you described. But if it's not VBO then the buffer is in system memory hence you can specify pointers. Upvoted! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Michael: Indeed. I covered this in the first paragraph: "They set the offset in either client (pointer in process address space) or server (offset into buffer object) space"